# C# Check If Java Is Installed && version(int)

Tags: c#

I'm making launcher for my java game and I want to check if java 8 is installed, because you can't run java application if java is not installed. I looked the answer on the internet and can't find answer to my question.

**My Current Code:**

```
string temp = GetJavaVersion();
string temp2 = temp.Substring(13, temp.Length - 13);
//string temp3 = temp2.Substring(10, temp2.Length - 1);
string installPath = temp2;
ShowMessageBox(installPath, "Debug", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

**GetJavaVersion() Method Code:**

```
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                new ProcessStartInfo("java", "-version ");

            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
            return proc.StandardError.ReadLine();

        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

**Output:**

```
"1.8.0_144"
```

Problem is that i get quotes and unnecessary numbers.(i just need number 8 to indicate that java version 8 is installed), if java isn't installed then just output 0.

Can Any One Help?

**Edit**
If i use `Regex` then how do i get number to int variable?
Code:

```
   string temp = GetJavaVersion();
   string temp2 = temp.Substring(13, temp.Length - 13);
   requiredJavaVersion = 8;
   //string temp3 = temp2.Substring(10, temp2.Length - 1);
   string regexPattern = @"([0-9]+)";
   Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern);
   //Error comes here
   int currentVersion = Convert.ToInt32(regex.Matches("1.8.0_144")[1]); 

   if (currentVersion == requiredJavaVersion)
   {
       hasRequiredVersion = true;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break your version into numbers with regex:

```
string regexPattern = @"([0-9]+)";
Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern);
```

This would return you an array with 4 results:

`1` `8` `0` `144`

Then get your `8` version like `regex.Matches("1.8.0_144")[1].Value;`

To convert this to **int** use

```
int value = int.Parse(regex.Matches("1.8.0_144")[1].Value);
```

Comment: Check Post again, i added new thing at EDIT

Comment: Edited answer, you should get a value from `Match`

Comment: Thanks for the Anwser.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LINQ as regex is expensive:

```
var result = "1.8.0_144";
var version = new string(result.SkipWhile(c => c != '.')
                               .Skip(1)
                               .TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c))
                               .ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(version); // 8
```